# Get current time and duration of audio in PositionalAudio element R3F drei

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

Basically i'm working on an interactive audio player which is overlayed on the scene, hence building this payer with drei and react three fiber. I have a couple of bugs, firstly i can't work out how to have the next track in the array play once the current track is over. I can't even get the value of the current time or duration of the track playing to print anywhere.
I would also love it if the next track would play automatically when you press forward or reverse, but right now you have to toggle the play state after skipping tracks to have the audio play again. The onEnded prop for the PositionalAudio element doesn't seem to do anything.

Here's the repo if you want to take a look at the project in full: https://github.com/matildasutho/skyline-radiofear_ozelot_2023/tree/main/ASCII_SKYLINE

I have been learning for a month so would welcome any other feedback

```
export default function PlaySound() {
    const [currentTrackIndex, setCurrentTrackIndex] = useState(0);
    const sound = useRef(null);
    const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false);
    const [colorPalette, setColorPalette] = useState(colorPalettes[0]);
    const [currentTime, setCurrentTime] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (sound.current && isPlaying) {
            sound.current.currentTime = currentTime; // Set the currentTime of the audio
            sound.current.play();
        } else if (sound.current) {
            sound.current.pause();
        }
    }, [currentTime, isPlaying]);

    const playPauseAudio = () => {
        setIsPlaying((prevIsPlaying) => {
            const newIsPlaying = !prevIsPlaying;
            if (newIsPlaying) {
                sound.current.play();
            } else {
                sound.current.pause();
            }
            console.log("Is playing:", newIsPlaying);
            return newIsPlaying;
        });
    };

    const changeTrack = (nextTrackIndex) => {
        sound.current.pause();
        setIsPlaying(false);
        setCurrentTime(0);
        setCurrentTrackIndex(
            (prevIndex) => (nextTrackIndex + tracks.length) % tracks.length
        );
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        if (isPlaying) {
            sound.current?.play();
        }
    }, [isPlaying]);

    const handleColorChange = (palette) => {
        setColorPalette(palette);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        const handleTrackEnded = () => {
            // Change the track index to the next one in the array
            const nextTrackIndex = (currentTrackIndex + 1) % tracks.length;
            changeTrack(nextTrackIndex);
        };

        // Add event listener for the 'ended' event on the audio element
        sound.current?.addEventListener("ended", handleTrackEnded);

        // Clean up the event listener when the component unmounts or the currentTrackIndex changes
        return () => {
            sound.current?.removeEventListener("ended", handleTrackEnded);
        };
    }, [currentTrackIndex]);

    const url = tracks[currentTrackIndex];
    const display = url.replace("/tracks/", " ░░░░░░░░");
    const duration = tracks[0].duration;
    console.log(duration);

    return (
        <>
            <Suspense fallback={null}>
                <PositionalAudio
                    url={tracks[currentTrackIndex]}
                    ref={(audio) => (sound.current = audio)}
                    onEnded={() => {
                        handleTrackEnded();
                    }}
                />
                {/* <Audio
                    src={tracks[currentTrackIndex]}
                    queNext={() => {
                        handleTrackEnded();
                    }}
                /> */}
                <AsciiEffect
                    sound={sound}
                    backGround={colorPalette.background}
                    foreGround={colorPalette.foreground}
                    characTers={colorPalette.characters}
                />
            </Suspense>

            <DashBoard
                ffaction={() => changeTrack(currentTrackIndex + 1)}
                rewaction={() => changeTrack(currentTrackIndex - 1)}
                toggleaction={playPauseAudio}
                trackDisplay={display}
                input={" "}
                button1={() => handleColorChange(colorPalettes[0])}
                button2={() => handleColorChange(colorPalettes[1])}
                button3={() => handleColorChange(colorPalettes[2])}
                button4={() => handleColorChange(colorPalettes[3])}
                button5={() => handleColorChange(colorPalettes[4])}
                button6={() => handleColorChange(colorPalettes[5])}
                // Add more buttons with color palettes as needed
            />
        </>
    );
}
```